# Indentation error in simple python

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

**Update:** The original question was posted using `C-RET` to run the lines, which produces the error. I get no such error using The menu `Python > Eval region`, which successfully evaluates the script.

However, using the menu for every execution is really annoying, and moreover I can't run the present line alone with that method. So my problem remains.

---

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure this out.

This code is giving me an IndentationError. I can't imagine what's going on.

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
```

[image]

Here's everything related to python in my emacs.el

```
;; elpy
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))
(package-initialize) 
(elpy-enable)
```

Comment: check if you have different indentation type on your script, e.g mixing tabs with spaces

Comment: @HarryPotfleur Thanks, but in this case they're all spaces put automatically by the python major mode.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. This can lead to some confusing errors.

I'd suggest using only tabs or only spaces for indentation.

Using only spaces is generally the easier choice. Most editors have an option for automatically converting tabs to spaces. If your editor has this option, turn it on.
You can paste your code in notepad to see.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not seeing that, however. If I run emacs' `untabify` to convert any tabs to spaces, it still doesn't work, so I'm thinking that might not be the problem.

Comment: The code works for me in Sublime 2. Take a look at [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/using-tab-key-for-indentation-in-python-repl-produces-strange-indentation-proble)

Answer (score 0):

All commands from menu have a command-name callable via M-x COMMAND RET.
In this case M-x `python-send-region` RET